# Limit on number of UIViewControllers to be pushed in UINavigationViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Does anybody know how many view controllers can be pushed on to UINavigationController. I understand that it depends upon the view controller's content (UIImages, etc. would require more memory) but I would like to know if there is any limit in general. I am not sure if Apple gives us any guideline regarding this as I have been trying to look for one but could not find so far. The reason that I am asking is I am trying to work on a book app which may have a few hundred pages and as I understand all the view controllers in UINavigationController stays in memory until we pop them so it might take up a lot of memory.

Other alternative I can think of to use CustomContainerViewController and then try to push one controller at a time while removing the previous one.

But I would like to know if its possible with UINavigationController though.

Comment: Why would you push a new view controller for each page? You only need one view controller that can display any page.

Comment: If your displaying a book, a `UIPageViewController` might work better for you.

Comment: @rmaddy- The reason I was thinking of multiple view controllers is to get the transitions from one page to another. Using one view controller, I can refresh the content but I don't think I can get the transitioning effect. I believe Brandon's suggestion of using UIPageViewController should do it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely memory limited as you mention though I do not know for sure.  Having several hundred UIViewControllers on a navigation stack is a poor choice.  Using a UIPageViewController would probably be a better choice.  You would only need three view controllers (left, current, and right) and you could cycle content between those three based on the page.